# How does terraform evaluates constants

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

How does terraform evaluate constants?

My team has below terraform code.

```
# main.tf file
locals {
  resource_prefix      = var.resource_context.constants.resource_prefix
  virtual_network_name = "${local.resource_prefix}MainVNet"
  subnets = {
    (var.subnet_keys.test1)      = "${local.resource_prefix}SubnetTest1",
    (var.subnet_keys.test2)      = "${local.resource_prefix}SubnetTest2",
    (var.subnet_keys.test3)      = "${local.resource_prefix}SubnetTest3",
    (var.subnet_keys.test4)      = "${local.resource_prefix}SubnetTest4",
    (var.subnet_keys.test5)      = "${local.resource_prefix}SubnetTest5"
    (var.subnet_keys.test6)      = "${local.resource_prefix}SubnetTest6"
  }
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = local.virtual_network_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_context.resource_group.name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {
  for_each             = local.subnets
  name                 = each.value
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_context.resource_group.name
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
}
```

```
# variables.tf file

variable "resource_context" {}
variable "subnet_keys" {
  type = object({
    test1      = string
    test2      = string
    test3      = string
    test4      = string
    test5      = string
    test6      = string
  })
}
```

I just want to know how terraform evaluates local variable resource_prefix in main.tf, I mean, suffix part of the local variable "constants.resource_prefix". Is there any special significance of it in that variable?

Its final value for one of the variable "${local.resource_prefix}SubnetTest1" will be
DevLabCu0SubnetTest1

Comment: Didn't quite understand the problem or the question. Could you add clarity?

Comment: The string will be interpolated as expected.

Comment: Do you have any issues with the current code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about the following expression from your snippet:

```
var.resource_context.constants.resource_prefix
```

Terraform internally understands this expression as two different parts:

- `var.resource_context` refers to the variable declared in `variable "resource_context"`. This is the part that Terraform uses to understand the dependency relationship implied by this expression.
- `.constants.resource_prefix` is an operation you're applying to that object, which has no special meaning to Terraform.

The `constants` in that second part in particular is just an arbitrary attribute name chosen by the author of this module, and isn't something inherent to Terraform at all. It might be clearer to see this by adding an explicit [type constraint](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/type-constraints.html) to `variable "resource_context"`, whereas the author of this module previously left the variable unconstrained and thus didn't specify which type is expected:

```
variable "resource_context" {
  type = object({
    constants = object({
      resource_prefix = string
    })
  })
}
```

The above type constraint states that the value for `var.resource_context` must be an object with an attribute named `constants`, which itself is an object with an attribute named `resource_prefix`. Notice that both of those names are totally arbitrary as far as Terraform is concerned, so you could rename `constants` to `thingies` and then write `var.resource_context.thingies.resource_prefix` and Terraform would consider that just as valid.

The Terraform language doesn't have any first-class sense of "named constants" that you might be familliar with in another language. Literal values like `"foo"` and `2` are *unnamed* constants, but because the Terraform language is declarative and therefore doesn't allow reassigning values to symbols at runtime there isn't any strong distinction between "constants" and "variables" in the way you might expect from an imperative programming language.

Comment: Yes, I was specifically asking about this one "var.resource_context.constants.resource_prefix".